# UIImageView's image disappears when changing the image

Tags: xcode, ios, xcode4

When changing the image on an UIImageView in code, the image disappears. This only happens on an iPod Touch device, not on the iPhone emulator.

In my bundle I have an image named `SomeImage.PNG`

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SomeImage" ofType:@"png"];
[self.background setImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]];
```

I must reiterate, this works fine on the iPhone simulator but not on an iPod Touch device.

Notice that the image file has an upper-case file extension, but in my code it is declared with lower case. This is the problem. So to fix the problem, change the code to this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SomeImage" ofType:@"PNG"];
[self.background setImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]];
```

I am asking if there is a 'better' way to do what I am doing, so I don't come across such issues in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. Unfortunately the iOS file system is case sensitive.

Something like this.....?

```
NSString *filename = @"SomeImage";
NSString *extension = @"png";
UIImage *img = nil;
NSString *path = nil;

path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:[extension lowercaseString]];
img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

if (img == nil) {
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:[extension uppercaseString]];
    img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a good answer, but probably unnecessary amount of code in the long run. I have learnt my lesson!